Selenium import on Mage.ai?
Can I use Selenium Webdriver within my pipeline?
I wrote it on requirements, however I get module import error, so Idk if it's just not supported. I'm doing everything with the web interface btw, since my workplace has been doing it like that.
I searched for an answer but I couldn't find their direct contact and their slack platform is half dead. I've seen a question similar to mine, regarding selenium usage, and they didn't respond.
I need it to track a website which doesn't have an API, in order to regularly check for and download a set of pdfs. ← If you know how do do this without using Selenium, inside Mage.Ai, I could use that too.

Every other module has been succesfully imported after placing it onto the requirements.txt file of utils. However, this particular one isn't. The file's content rn is:
pandas==1.1.5
pyodbc==4.0.39
pyyaml>=1.1.1
pysmb==1.2.10
beautifulsoup4=4.9.3
pywin32>=308
selenium>=4.26.1

I tried downgrading the version and yet nothing.
I'm importing it using (this is a test code I wrote to check the correct function of Selenium on this page):
if 'data_loader' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import data_loader
if 'test' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import test
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

@data_loader
def scrap_data(*args, **kwargs):
    # Configure Chrome options for headless mode
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

    # Set up the Chrome driver
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    # Example: Open a webpage and perform some actions
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/?hl=es')
    print(driver.title)

The raised error is this:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mage_ai/data_preparation/models/block/__init__.py:2039, in Block._execute_block(self, outputs_from_input_vars, custom_code, dynamic_block_index, dynamic_block_indexes, dynamic_upstream_block_uuids, execution_partition, from_notebook, global_vars, input_vars, logger, logging_tags, input_from_output, runtime_arguments, upstream_block_uuids, run_settings, data_integration_runtime_settings, execution_partition_previous, **kwargs)
   2037 if custom_code is not None and custom_code.strip():
   2038     if BlockType.CHART != self.type:
-> 2039         exec(custom_code, results)
   2040 elif self.content is not None:
   2041     exec(self.content, results)
File <string>:6
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'


@K J My mistake, I meant I gotta print a set of pdfs, with random names. The pdf is not in sight unless I click the element and open the popup window because this MailBoxes page just won't let me access it if I do not enable PDF Popups, so I guess I gotta do all the job (also with chrome + selenium, I can set up the correct printer, after stablishing connection with win32 module) :(
